# PJSIP apjsua ndk-build using cygwin and swing "No such file or directory" error

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

I've followed PJSIP tutorial for Android and I was successful with Building PJSIP. But I got stuck with Building apjsua sample application.
I use windows Vista with CYGWIN and SWING. I started cygwin as administrator on Vista with switched UAC off. My target is Android project in Eclipse.

After start ndk-build in ...pjsip-apps/src/apjsua directory this error output appears:

```
Invoking SWIG...
swig -o jni/pjsua_app_wrap.c -package org.pjsip.pjsua -outdir src/org/pjsip/pjsua -java jni/pjsua_app.i
Unable to open file src\org\pjsip\pjsua\pjsua_appJNI.java: No such file or directory
make: *** [jni/pjsua_app_wrap.c] Error 1
```

If I create folder ...src\org\pjsip\pjsua\ outside cygwin and start ndk-build once more this output appears:

```
Invoking SWIG...
swig -o jni/pjsua_app_wrap.c -package org.pjsip.pjsua -outdir src/org/pjsip/pjsua -java jni/pjsua_app.i
d:/.../swig -o jni/pjsua_app_wrap.c -package org.pjsip.pjsua -outdir d:/.../PjSipAndroid/pjsip-apps/src/apjsua/src/org/pjsip/pjsua/ -java jni/pjsua_app.i
Compile thumb  : pjsua_app <= pjsua_app_wrap.c
SharedLibrary  : libpjsua_app.so
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: /cygdrive/d/.../PjSipAndroid/pjsip-apps/build/output/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi/*.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libpjsua_app.so] Error 1
```

Can anybode tell me what I do wrong ?